# react-router-dom navigation and vertical scroll in a React Vite Application

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, single-page-application, vite, vertical-scrolling

I would like to have a vertical scroll for single-page application scrolling from hero section all the way down to contacts. I would like to be able to scroll to the section upon clicking the correspondent route in the navbar. For example, if I click "Projects", I'd like the page to automatically scroll down to this section. I am used to have it very simple with NextJS pages, but since I've switched to Vite, I can't achieve the same result.

I am using react-router-dom routes, below is my App.tsx

```
// App.tsx

import { Box, ThemeProvider, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { theme } from './theme';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Hero } from './components/Hero';
import { About } from './components/About';
import { Contact } from './components/Contact';
import { Projects } from './components/Projects';
import { Navbar } from './components/Navbar';
import { PageLayout } from './layout/PageLayout';

const NoMatch = () => {
  return (
    <Box style={{ padding: 20 }}>
      <Typography variant='h1'>404: Page Not Found</Typography>
      <Typography paragraph>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip.
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  );
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <PageLayout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Hero />} />
            <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
            <Route path='/projects' element={<Projects />} />
            <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path='*' element={<NoMatch />} />
          </Routes>
        </PageLayout>
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

And here is PageLayout.tsx where I hoped to achieve the vertical scroll:

```
// PageLayout.tsx

import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

interface PageLayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export const PageLayout = ({ children }: PageLayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: '100vh',
        overflowY: 'auto',
        scrollBehavior: 'smooth',
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

```
// Navbar.tsx

import { AppBar } from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Link to='/' style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        Home
      </Link>
      <Link to='/about' style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        About
      </Link>
      <Link to='/projects' style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        Projects
      </Link>
      <Link to='/contact' style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        Contact
      </Link>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
```

to='/' seems to have no effect for an automatic scrolling to the correspondent page. I tried including id="" to my sections, but it doesn't work.

I tried other stuff like placing the components into App.tsx but then I do not have my routes since the components are rendered in any case.

In conclusion, the vertical scroll doesn't work. There is no scrolling at all, I only see the hero page and if I click any other page in the navbar, I just get routed to this page.

Please help me to solve this weird issue!

Comment: If you want a Single Page App then don't use a routing library that is used to simulate a Multiple Page App. Sounds like you should remove all the routes and render all the content on the same page and use hash links to link to each section.